# Can't store session data after session_regenerate_id();

Tags: php, session

I have a webpage where I would like to regenerate the session id when the user logs in. The issue I am having is I run `session_regenerate_id();` and then try attaching `$_SESSION['user'] = $row;` where $row is an array.

I have tried everything in the book, for e.g destroying session and then starting again. I have been working on it for at least 2 hours and I have no solution.

I have removed a lot of irrelevant php and left some in so you get the gist of what I am trying to do but here's the script

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["CSRF"])){
        $_SESSION["CSRF"] = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 10);
    }
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        if($_POST["action"]==="login"){
            //querying DB for $_POST values
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
            $login_ok = false;          
            $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
            if($row){ 
                $checked = //check password is okay
                if ($checked) {
                    $login_ok = true; 
                }
            }
            if($login_ok) { 
                session_regenerate_id();                
                unset($row['salt']); 
                unset($row['password']); 
                $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have also tried with no luck.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["CSRF"])){
        $_SESSION["CSRF"] = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 10);
    }
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        if($_POST["action"]==="login"){

            //querying DB for $_POST values
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
            $login_ok = false;          
            $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
            if($row){ 
                $checked = //check password is okay
                if ($checked) {
                    $login_ok = true; 
                }
            }
            if($login_ok) {                 
                unset($row['salt']); 
                unset($row['password']); 
                $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
                $arr = $_SESSION;               
                session_regenerate_id(true);
                $_SESSION = $arr;
            }
        }
    }
```

### EDIT

Sorry I didn't clarify the title but basically  I'll try storing the current session in a variable and I'll regenerate the session id and add try adding the stored session variable into the new session, however the session id does not contain the old data, and I am not getting any errors.

Comment: Are you storing your session data in a database?  If so, what does the table look like?  Is the new session id there after running session_regenerate_id()?  Also what is the value of session.use_trans_sid (use ini_get to find out) as this can interfere with regenerating the session

Comment: I am not storing my sessions in database and session.use_trans_sid is set to 0 :/

Comment: What isn't working? Is the row not saved to the session, is the session id not changing? Are you getting the 'old' session (i.e. lacking the 'user' row) on subsequent requests or are you getting an empty session? Could you clarify on that? And try setting your `error_reporting` to something pretty verbose, as it might provide a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: Sorry I should I have clarified the title a bit more in the content, basically I'll store the current session in a variable and I'll regenerate the session id and add try adding the stored session variable into the new session, however the session id does not contain the old data, and I am not getting any errors.

Comment: @YusafKhaliq Are you saying that when you regenerate the session id, the old data is not persisting, even if you store the old data into a temporary variable and pass it along to the new session?

Comment: Check the result of session_regenerate_id and make sure that it's returning true.

Comment: Also ... make sure that the INI configuration for "session.use_trans_sid" is set to 0.

Comment: @Kyle yes exactly, and i know it may seem pointless but when I replace the line `session_regenerate_id(true);` in the second block of code with `unset($_SESSION);` it still works and allows me to log in, and the stored data in the variable is passed on.

Comment: yupp session.use_trans_sid is set to 0 :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem once, but this really is just a shot in the dark because it was such a specific case.

I had two domains, **www.domain.com** and **secure.domain.com**. When I went to www.domain.com it set a cookie, however in the [cookie params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) I set the domain to `.domain.com`, which means that it was used for domain.com and all sub-domains.

Then on secure.domain.com, I also used session cookies, however the domain used in the cookie was `secure.domain.com` (i.e. it would only work on the `secure` subdomain). to check if the user was logged in, I did something along the lines of `if (isset($_SESSION['username']))` to check if it was set in the session, but since domain.com didn't use the array key `username` in its sessions, it was receiving the session cookie domain.com without that. Then when I logged in, I would set the `username` and all worked perfectly fine, up until the point when I regenerated the session ID. As soon as I did this, the user was immediately logged out again. It really took me a long time to figure out what was happening, but basically I was left with *two* session cookies on the browser, one that was sent to `.domain.com` and the other sent to `secure.domain.com` and they were conflicting with each other.

This can be fixed in two ways:

1. make the cookie from the main domain only be for the `www` subdomain and not ALL subdomains.
2. Use a different [`session_name()`](http://php.net/session_name) for one of the domains. This was what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that $login_ok gets set to true? You could print something there to be sure. From my test (simplified version of your script), it seem to work ok:

```
<?php
session_start();
$data = $_SESSION['data'];
$sid = session_id();
echo "Old data is $data<br>Sid is $sid<br>";
if($_GET["action"]==="login"){
    session_regenerate_id();                
    $_SESSION['data'] = $data + 1;
}
$data = $_SESSION['data'];
$sid = session_id();
echo "New data is $data\n<br>Sid is $sid\n<br>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest :), Yes it is set to true, when I remove the session session_regenerate_id(); line, it logs in perfectly fine.

Comment: Try also my script and see what it prints. It should print different old/new info when ...?action=login and same info otherwise.

Comment: I got Old data is Array Sid is ns1gv3ojilnbma3k7bm73qun01
 New data is Sid is qgh8drb5cknfq3vv28u151o5o1

Comment: You probably had already stored in session since you got "Array". You must also reload the page a few times with/without action=login to see if it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but why are you reassigning the content of $_SESSION? session_regenerate_id() doesn't null out the content of session, it just gives the session a new ID - the content of the session is still the same as before the regeneration. So there is no need to reassign values.

Hence, it should be perfectly valid to do this:

```
if($login_ok) {                 
  unset($row['salt']); 
  unset($row['password']); 
  $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
  session_regenerate_id();
}
```

No need to reasssign.

Also, you should always check to see if a session is already started before starting the session, so do this at the beginning: `if (session_id()) { session_start(); }` instead of just `session_start()`.